# Postgresql error, how can I fix that issue?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am new to postgres before I was using MySQL now i am programming a registration Website I use this code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      require("mysql.php");
      $result = pg_prepare($conn, "login_query", "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE USERNAME = $1");
      $result = pg_execute($conn, "login_query", [$_POST["username"]]);
      //$stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST["username"]);
      //$stmt->execute();
     // $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($conn -> connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn -> conect_error);
    }

    if($result -> num_rows > 0){

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["USERNAME"]. "<br>";
          }
        } else {
          echo "0 results";
        }
     //   $conn->close();
    }

      if($count == 0){
        if($_POST["pw"] == $_POST["pw2"]){
          $result = pg_prepare($conn, "ins_query", "INSERT INTO accounts (USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ($1, $2)");
          $result = pg_execute($conn, "ins_query", [$_POST["username"]]);
          //$stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST["username"]);
          $hash = password_hash($_POST["pw"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
          $result = pg_execute($conn, "ins_query", [$hash]);
         // $stmt->bindParam(":pw", $hash);
        //  $stmt->execute();
          echo "<p class=pinreg> Dein Account wurde angelegt. </p>";
          header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
          echo "<p class=pinreg> Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein! </p>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<p class=pinreg> Der Benutzername ist bereits vergeben! </p>";
      }
     ?>
```

Running that i get following errors.

[image]

Comment: You have all informations in error message. In pg_prepare you have query with 2 params. In pg_execute you bind only one.

Comment: _Side note:_ You should add all error messages as text as well. People tend to search for error messages and it would help them find this.

Comment: _Side note 2:_ You have another issue as well (the last "Cannot modify header information") that will still be there after you've fixed the DB issue. Any call to `header()` _must_ be before _any_ output at all so you can't have any `echo` or anything before it. (which also doesn't make sense to have since the user wouldn't be able to read it anyway if they get redirected away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$result = pg_execute($conn, "ins_query", [$_POST["username"]]);` calls only provide 1 parameter at a time, namely you pass username on one call and password on the next one. Merge the calls, and as the error suggests "provide the 2 required input on the function, instead of the 1 you are passing" now

```
$result = pg_execute($conn, "ins_query", [$_POST["username"], $hash]);
```